# Change the default magnifier to hover in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have done a custom theme in Magento 2. I have to change the magnifier to hover event. Means see the bellow section of view.xml

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width">1200</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height">1200</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

But still it is happening when i ckick the product image. I guess you understand i am trying. I simple want to change the click event to hover event.

I have used a extension also. But it is not working. I think i have missed something else here. I am new in Magento 2. I think it is a simple problem. But i have spent my 4 hours to solve this.

Advance thank you.

Comment: Can you reply anyone ?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this yet? I think it's related to your product images `dimensions` and `resolution`. Try to put something big like `1920x2400`. 
Note that the file will be reduced by a `PHP` library when you upload through the admin panel.  You need also to modify default image size to prevent Magento to reduce the `1920x2400`

Comment: No it is also not working. I have tried before. I did this by a module. Really cant get the solution yet.